# how to use nvl on a regexp_like product

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

please can someone help with a SQL problem?
I have a query which currently accepts an external parameter which can be null or a single value such as 'STR1' .

This is handled by a query in format below:

```
select a.refe_id  from a,  b,  c
where a.owln_code = c.code
and c.con_id =  b.pers_id
and b.con_abbrv = nvl(:PARAM, b.con_abbrv)
and a.status = '01'
```

In the future the external parameter can have a single value, null, or multiple values separated by pipes e.g STR1|STR2|STR3|

I am now at the stage below in accomodating this but have lost the nvl test that allows a match through all rows in table b if the parameter is null.
Please can someone help with how to do this? I have searched the net and tried to do it myself. Thanks very much in advance.

```
select a.refe_id  from a,  b,  c
where a.owln_code = c.code
and c.con_id =  b.pers_id
and regexp_like(:PARAM, '(^|)' || b.con_abbrv|| '(|$)')
and a.status = '01'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend something like this:

```
select a.refe_id  from a,  b,  c
where a.owln_code = c.code
  and c.con_id =  b.pers_id
  and (:PARAM IS NULL OR regexp_like(:PARAM, '(^|)' || b.con_abbrv|| '(|$)'))
  and a.status = '01'
```

Not related, but I'd also recommend using explicit join syntax: I think you'll find it makes the query easier to read because it separates the JOIN logic from the WHERE logic:

```
select a.refe_id  from a
join c on a.owln_code = c.code
join b on c.con_id =  b.pers_id
where (:PARAM IS NULL OR regexp_like(:PARAM, '(^|)' || b.con_abbrv|| '(|$)'))
  and a.status = '01'
```

Comment: Ahh, Yes, works perfectly in all scenarios. Well done Ed and thanks very much. I'll mark your answer as correct. take care, Dave